# Archived app wont appear on organizer after a few updates

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, updates

I was compiling my app and archiving it correctly with no problem whatsoever. I added a charts library to the app, did some stuff with it, archived it fine but Apple didnt let me upload it because the library wasnt correctly referenced in the app.
So I fixed that problem and tried to archive it again, **but it just wont appear on the organizer.**

- Skip install is set to NO
- Archive in the scheme is checked
- Reveal archive in organizer is also checked

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply try this steps:

- Reopen your project
- Clean Xcode & Remove derived data
- Change build number & version number
- Make archive now

**Note:**

- You are able make archive earlier, so it could work perfect after this steps. Unless you have changed any settings in Xcode.

**Edit:**

- Go to targets - build settings & find "Installation Directory". Make sure there is "$(LOCAL_APPS_DIR)" added.
- Go to Edit Scheme -> Build tab, Make sure you have archive check box selected. Check image below:
  [image]
- Go to Edit Scheme -> Archive tab & make sure the check box "Reveal in organizer selected"
- See below image:
  [image]

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I did all things you listed and still wont appear in the organizer... :S

Comment: Yes @Mack "Reveal archive in Organizer" is checked. Any other idea? Thanks

Comment: @PabloDuque one more thing make sure that your source must be on mac. Don't try with make archive from source who is in server.

Comment: In Edit Scheme, build tab, Archive was indeed selected. However I didnt have the instalation directory as $(LOCAL_APPS_DIR), changed it. However my problem persist and still wont show on the organizer. Any other idea? thanks!

Comment: So I went to the directory where Archives are stored and I found all the archives there, however the organizer wont show them. Tried to open it with XCode and said that the archive could not be open that it might be corrupted.... Any ideas on that? Thank you !

Comment: I didnt want to, I just need to upload  to the app store

Comment: something went wrong while archiving since its size is 0 bytes.... Im thinking I might've done something wrong when referencing the libraries

Comment: Reinstall Xcode & from current project Remove Derived data & try again.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long in answering, I reinstall it, removed derived data and still wont work. I still think it has something to do with the changes I made trying to link the library. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @PabloDuque have you reinstalled xcode ? If so than there might be some settings changed in your project. Create new demo project & try to make archive of it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old item... However, I encountered the same issue today and tried all the above suggestions and still no luck.

Was able to work around it by using Finder and going to the build > iOS > archive folder of the application.  Then right click on the .xcarchive file and open with Xcode.